# Como deve ser visto o proselitismo político no Stack Overflow em Português?

Tags: debate, comportamento, moderação

O proselitismo é o intento ou empenho de converter pessoas ou grupos, a uma determinada crença ou ideia.
O proselitismo político é o intento ou empenho de converter pessoas ou grupos, a uma determinada ideologia, partido ou corrente política.

Hoje (14/09/2022) já começo a ver usuários brasileiros a embutirem nos nomes dizeres políticos e conhecendo o ufanismo político brasileiro confesso que me surgiram alguns questionamentos:

- Trazer suas preferências políticas para o site é democracia ou ruído?
- É saudável os usuários se auto segregarem politicamente aqui no site?
- Levando em conta o alcance global do site, realmente é desejável sujeitar nossos usuários às peculiaridades políticas regionalizadas?
- Discussões por motivos puramente políticos serão toleradas? Como serão tratadas?
- Devido a nossa expertise muitos de nós somos contratados como analistas de dados para partidos políticos em época de campanha. Como distinguir paixão ideológica de spam?
- Há o risco de que o Stack Overflow em Português vire um Twitter?

Comment: Eu vi nos nicknames por enquanto, acho complicado discutir essa parte que é muito pessoal, agora, se o assunto for para o conteúdo (perguntas e respostas, comentários), provavelmente vai ser tratado como qualquer outro spam.

Comment: 14/09/2222, [Back to the Future](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eVBc.gif)

Comment: No perfil, incluindo foto, opinião pessoal (desde que não ofensivo) não vejo problema.

Comment: @Bacco e "nicknames", bios e etc não deixam de ser conteúdos e não deixam de serem aplicados às regras do site?

Comment: Discussões relacionadas: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349131 | https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339999/401803

Comment: @CypherPotato são sujeitos às regras obviamente, mas qual regra estaria sendo quebrada no caso de um apelido com manifestação de preferência pessoal? Tem que analisar por esse critério.

Comment: @Bacco apelidos pessoais não incomodam pessoas desde que não manifestem opinião pública.

Comment: @CypherPotato a questão não é nossa interpretação (tem muita coisa que eu não gosto no site, mas aplico as regras do site, não as minhas) - O ponto do meu comentário anterior foi levantar "pra galera" esse questionamento, apesar de uns não gostarem, existe alguma regra de fato sendo violada? Se tiver regra violada, não pode. Se não tiver regra violada, nada a fazer (mesmo eu não gostando da idéia). Eu obviamente sou contra usar esse espaço para manifestação de ideologia, mas outros podem não gostar de "jogo de nave" e pra esses meu avatar atual "seria mais ofensivo que política". Como faz? //

Comment: Acho que o cerne da questão é se tais manifestações são ou não compatíveis com o propósito do StackOverflow e isso é suficiente para pensar nas regras da comunidade se ainda não há uma que proíba.

Comment: Muito tempo estava sem entrar no SOpt, entrei e me deparei com isso. Resumindo: continuarei longe. "Que tistreza".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Até onde eu sei da política da SE que devemos seguir, envolve dois pontos simples:

1. Qualquer conteúdo postado que seja fora do escopo do site deve ser removido, a não ser que seja importante para o foco principal do conteúdo.

   Então qualquer conteúdo político em postagens deve ser sinalizado para moderadores fazerem algo se for necessário, e moderadores comunitários podem editar e já retirar imediatamente onde é possível.
2. Qualquer conteúdo não ofensivo e que não fira as regras estabelecidas, considerando que adolescentes podem acessar, que o usuário coloque em seu perfil, nome de usuário ou avatar é permitido, inclusive podem fazer propaganda do que quiser.

   Portanto conteúdo político nessa área é um direito do usuário e não devamos fazer nada, desde que claro, não envolva crimes, inclusive eleitorais, e que cause real problema. É um direito do usuário se expressar como quiser e ser julgado por isso.

Goste ou não, é a política adotada. O conteúdo postado é da comunidade, o conteúdo do perfil é do usuário, desde que ele não cometa crimes ali, ainda que pequenos, como difamações e injúrias.

Devemos manter atenção e não deixar nada que desvie do objetivo do site aconteça, sem impedir a pessoa se expressar em seu espaço próprio. Não acredito que se transforme em grande problema, o que não aconteceu há 4 ou 8 anos atrás.